# Finding $P(XY \le a)$ when $x<y$ and the distribution of both is uniform

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint pdf
>
> $$f_{XY}(x,y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1,  &0 < x <1,\ \ x < y < x+1 \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Find $P(XY \le a)$

I am going to solve this using the CDF method with integration.

Based on the information given, my setup is the following:

$$0 < x < y < 1 \\ x < y < x+1 < 2 \\ xy < a$$

I will make a diagram, where the blue curve represents an example of $0<a<1$, and the green curve represents an example of $1<a<2$:

[image]

For $0<a<1$, I will integrate:

$$\int_0^a \int_0^{\min \{{a \over y}, \ y\}}\, dx \ dy $$

For $1<a<2$, I will integrate:

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{\min \{{a \over y},\ 1 \}}\, dx \ dy $$

My question is twofold:

1. Are my steps correct so far, and if not, where am I going wrong?
2. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What is $P(XY)$?

Comment: Should I write $P(XY<a)$ instead?

Comment: $P(XY\le a)$ would be the distribution function of $XY$. The derivative of that wrt $a$ would give the density of $XY$.

Comment: If you only want the expected value of $XY$ it's

$E(XY)=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{x+1} x\cdot y \cdot f_{XY}(x,y) dydx$

Comment: @papasmurfete, thank you, that does make sense now that I think about it, that it is unnecessary to find $P(XY\le a)$. Nevertheless, since I started with this $P(XY\le a)$ business I would like to finish it.

Comment: In order to find $f_Z(z)$ for $Z=XY$ you should use the following:

 $f_Z(z)=\int f_{X,Y}(\frac{z}{y},y)\cdot \frac{1}{|y|} dy$

but you have to be very careful with the limits of the integral, and then you can find $F_z(z)$